# Compare 2 files, if a term is found copy that line into new file

Tags: bash

Currently I have 2 files, both tab delimited tables, and I want to search through file 2 and check if the terms in file 1 are found. If they are I want it to write to a new file.

The first 3 lines from file 2:

```
OTU1    243622  208679  121420  265864  0   0   2   0   0   11  1   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   839604  OTU1    -   Archaea 100%    Euryarchaeota   100%    Methanobacteria 100%    Methanobacteriales  100%    Methanobacteriaceae 100%    Methanobrevibacter  100%
OTU2    84366   120817  15834   74737   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   295755  OTU2    -   Archaea 100%    Euryarchaeota   100%    Methanobacteria 100%    Methanobacteriales  100%    Methanobacteriaceae 100%    Methanobrevibacter  100%
OTU3    69  755 26301   64521   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The first 3 lines of file 1:

```
"T2"    "T1"    "T3"    "T4"
"OTU19" 0   -0.437896457691538  0.31428903747861    0.619419210019158
"OTU25" 0   -0.29142378361388   -1.32473342078438   0.359748539739627
"OTU33" 0   -1.07342236097376   -0.0136125408176803 0.00324835637083578
```

I have this code at the moment which worked fine previously but doesnt on these files. Does anyone have a clue as to why?

```
cat file1 | xargs -I % grep "%       " file2 > file1.results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
    for word in $(tr -cs '[0-9a-zA-z ]' '\n' < file1)
    do 

       grep -o $word file2 >> file1.results   

    done
```

In case you do not want any word to be appended in `file1.results` then you can write one
`if` condition in internal `for` and skip that iteration by using `continue` inside if condition.
Like:

```
#!/bin/bash

    for word in $(tr -cs '[0-9a-zA-z ]' '\n' < file1)
    do 

       if [ "$word" == '0' ]; then
          continue
       fi

       grep -o $word file2 >> file1.results   

    done
```